# Cannot add the express-messages middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to add the express-messages middleware to a node.js application. I have followed the instructions on the github page [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-messages)

```
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});
```

But in the code, I get this error. Does anyone know why it complains about the package?

[image: express-messages error]

Comment: what is the version of express in your project?

Comment: It is express@4.17.1

Comment: npm install -D @types/module-name Can you try installing this way ? And re-run it.